# What is the difference between Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles and Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

I am folloing Shaun Wildermuth's instructions, in order to run my first basic ASPNet app. He refers to Microsift.AspNet.StaticFiles, but the closest I find is "Microsoft.Owin.StaticFile" thru "Manage NuGet Packages..." option in VisualStudio 2015.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles is the package for new the ASP.NET Core (formely ASP.NET 5 and ASP.NET vNext). The other package Microsoft.Owin.StaticFile is for the current ASP.NET 4.5. ASP.NET Core is still in prelease and thus the packages also. When you are developing a ASP.NET 5 application add the package as following:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles -Pre
```

In order to use the static files configure the middleware to add static files. This can be done inside the Startup.Configure method.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
  ...
  // Add static files to the request pipeline.
  app.UseStaticFiles();
  ...
```